# Toggle Between Specific Button in PHP

Tags: jquery, toggle

i am generating button by foreach loop and create an toggle using jquery but when i press it toggle between every button i want to toggle my div on specific clicked button
Button

```
 <button  class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-block addurl"><a><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> Buy Now</a></button>

My Jquery
$(".addurl").click(function(){
            $(".addurls").toggle("slow", function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });
```

here #addurls is the div which toggle

Comment: In code you have `$(".addurls")` but in text you say `#addurls`, what is it?

Comment: Its an typo mistake its class ,addurls

Comment: want to show toggle div below specific button clicked which is generating by foreach on based of product id

Comment: Please include all relevant code. Without all the code we cant see why it's not working

Comment: its all code i just want to know how i can toggle form below specific button because i am generating multiple button as record get from databsae using loop when i press a button it toggle form between all the generated button please tell me how i can show form just below the button press

Comment: There is no element in your code with the class `addurls`. Also you say ` i am generating multiple button` show us how you do that